# Missing template errors with strange path shown

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5

This is not ColdFusion specific, but the server is ColdFusion 10 on Windows Server.

About once a day I'll get a log file of a string of missingtemplate errors, and I can't figure out if this is a typo somewhere on my part, or a user doing something, or some sort of exploration exploit.

The most recent one from last night doesn't seem like it affects the user, as by following `CGI.QUERY_STRING` I can see they come to the home page, hit our `login_action.cfm` page to log in, get into the logged in area and then again following the `CGI.QUERY_STRING` I can see what pages they were on by the URL variables.

The missing template target page argument is always this:

```
TARGETPAGE  /https:/secure.domain.com/index.cfm
```

Which shows this for path translated and script name

```
PATH_TRANSLATED D:\web\site\https:\secure.domain.com\index.cfm 
SCRIPT_NAME /https:/secure.domain.com/index.cfm
```

After she logs in I can see by the CGI dump that she is indeed logged in OK

```
PATH_TRANSLATED D:\web\site\https:\secure.domain.com\user\login\index.cfm
```

Under the query_string I'll be able to see what pages she's on with `?p=home`, `?p=editaccount`  (URL would be `index.cfm?p=home` etc.)

I don't believe this is malicious, nothing is exposed to the user as far as error reporting, but nonetheless I'd like to figure out why / how this happens about once per day on this application, and understand how it does not seem to effect the user on the site yet throws these missingtemplate errors.

Comment: This has got to be something within your application. Does it always happen from the same page (URL)? Is it always directing to your site's home page as in your example (https:/secure.domain.com/index.cfm)? Does your application accept any user input that gets translated into a URL? Does your application have any automated redirects (cflocation) that may be the culprit? Are you using any URL rewriting rules from the web server that may be the culprit? Does your applications error handling attempt to redirect to the homepage on error? Just some thoughts on things to check.

Comment: Does your Application.cfc file have an onError method?  Does it send you relevant information to help you solve problems like this?

Comment: @DanBracuk - it's not firing onError - it's firing onMissingTemplate, which sends me the targetpage argument and a dump of the CGI scope.  I'm not sure if there's other variables I could add into that that might help track this down though.

Comment: @Miguel-F - agreed it's in the application.  This user went to the home page, logged in and then to about 10 pages in our logged in area - which leads me to believe it's not actually effecting the user experience because if it sent her to the home page (which is what onMisstingTemplate does) it would have logged her out.  No user input to URL.  It does have some cflocations, but it seems so random - maybe once per day out of 500-1000 user sessions per day.  onError isn't thrown - just missing template which sends me targetpage and CGI scope dump.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a malformed link somewhere in your app.

Look at the referrer of the error page, then inspect that previous page on the client side (as a user).

Also look at the user agent. It could be a browser trying to pre-fetch pages - and I'm assuming one is from a malformed link.